# Submodule fixed by Galois

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension and $R$ be a $K$-algebra. Then $G:=Gal(L/K)$ acts on $R \otimes_K L$ and on $(R \otimes_K L)^{\times}$ by acting on the right (on $L$).

Is it true that $(R \otimes_K L)^{G} = R$ and  $((R \otimes_K L)^{\times})^G = R^{\times}$ ?

The inclusions $\supseteq$ are clear but for me $\subseteq$ is less obvious. If $\sum_j r_j \otimes y_j$ is fixed by $G$, what can I say?
(Maybe it might use the fact that $H^1(G, (L,+)) = 0$ and $H^1(G, L^{\times})=0$...)

Thank you.

Comment: Applying prop. 27.51, p.487 from [Milne's notes](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/qg-fall2016/Milne_iAG.pdf), we have $$H^0(Gal(\bar K/K), Res_{L/K}G(\bar K)) = H^0(Gal(\bar L/L), G(\bar L))$$ where $G$ is the additive or the multiplicative group in my context. Then clearly, $L^{Gal(L/K)} = K$ and $(L^*)^{Gal(L/K)} = K^*$.

Comment: See also Lemma III.7.16. in Berhuy's Galois cohomology

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is at all deep. Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be a $K$-basis of
$R$. Then the elements of $R\otimes_K L$ all have the form $\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\otimes y_j$. This is fixed by $G$ iff all $y_j\in L^G=K$.

A unit in $R\otimes_K L$ is fixed by $G$ iff it lies in $R$. I suppose its
inverse may be in $R\otimes_K L$ but not in $K$. But its inverse
is also fixed by $G$ so lies in $R$. Thus a unit in $((R\otimes K_L)^\times)^G$ is a unit of $R$.

Comment: Thank you. But I would like a proof of "This is fixed by $G$ iff all $y_j\in L^G=K$.", which is the main point of my question. I'm not even sure why $a \otimes y = a \otimes \sigma(y) \in R \otimes_K L$ should imply $y = \sigma(y)$.

Comment: $\sigma:\sum a_j\otimes y_j\mapsto\sum a_j\otimes\sigma(y_j)$, so this is fixed by $ \sigma$ iff $\sigma(y_j)=y_j$ for all $j$.

Comment: I don't understand the "only if" part (while the "if" part is obvious). I repeat my comment above ; assume that $n=1$ in your notations, and that $x = a_1 \otimes y_1$ is fixed by $\sigma$, i.e. $a_1 \otimes y_1 = a_1 \otimes \sigma(y_1)$. Why does it follow that $y_1 = \sigma(y_1)$ ?

Comment: The $a_j$ form a **basis** for $R$.